# Void function with two arguments but not both need to be used

Tags: java, android, null, arguments, robotics

First Tech Challenge, A robotics organization now has an android platform instead of Lego. My team is transitioning to java but I have one simple question. If I have a function that has two arguments `power1` and `power2` and both can be set to a double but if the second one isn't specified, it shall run both motors with only the `power1` variable. Here is my code:

```
package com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.opmodes;

public class BasicFunctions extends HardwareAccess {

    /*
    This file lists some basic funcions on the robot that we can use without typing large amounts of code.
    To use this code in the opmode add "extends BasicFunctions" to the end of the class line
     */
    public void setDriveMotorPower(double power1, double power2) {
        if (power2 = null) {
            motorLeft.setPower(power1);
            motorRight.setPower(power1);
        }

        motorLeft.setPower(power1);
        motorRight.setPower(power2);

    }

    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public void loop() {

    }
}
```

**Update:** Here is a screenshot of Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: How to have it work since the code doesn't run

Comment: You probably meant: `power2 == null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. A primitive `double` can't be `null`, you'll have to use the [`java.lang.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) wrapper.
2. `=` is the assignment operator. Testing equality is done with the `==` operator.
3. You are using `power1` and `power2` after the `if` regardless of whether it was executed or not. Instead, you probably meant to use an `else` clause:

```
public void setDriveMotorPower(Double power1, Double power2) {
    motorLeft.setPower(power1);
    if (power2 == null) {
        motorRight.setPower(power1);
    } else {
        motorRight.setPower(power2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change the = to == and also I just forgot the else statement... but by the way, the code says that the double can't be null still

Comment: @LeoForney I noted this on my first point but neglected to fix the code - you should use `Double`, not `double`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Oh ok... and it now works, but what is the difference between `double` and `Double`

Comment: @LeoForney `double` is a primitive, `Double` is its wrapper class. You can read more about it in [this chapter of the java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html).

Comment: Some numbers give floats also, how would I go about making sure that if it is a float, I can convert it to a double and pass it though? Also, when I give the function one power of 0.73, it says `Double cannot be applied to double`

Answer (score 0):

If a function has 2 paramters, you have to send them both but there is another idea: If you don't wanna use `power2` for example you can pass it with some value that is impossible to happen like -1 or anything according to your situation then check `if(power2 == -1)` and that's better than checking for null.
By the way, the method `.setPower()` for will be called 4 times because you just used `if` not `if else`. It should be like

```
motorLeft.setPower(power1);
if (power2 == null) { // or -1 like I said before
        motorRight.setPower(power1);
} else {
    motorRight.setPower(power2);
}
```

Comment: actually, if you pass -1 through the .setPower() function it will make the motors spin backwards with 100% power. Also, your code needs a double equal sign like `==` and it still says that a double can't be null :(

Comment: @LeoForney no problem at all, I said for example -1, not you must use -1 "because in many cases -1 is the impossible values".  and thanks for the note about "=" :)

Comment: It makes way more sense to check for null than to check for some random integer.